# Read text from file in a (sub)directory

Tags: java

```
public static String parse(String fileName) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String workDir = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
    String pkgDir = "/src/test/resources/app/testcases/";
    String absoluteFilePath = workDir.concat(pkgDir).concat(fileName);
    Files.lines(Paths.get(absoluteFilePath.replace("\\", "/")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .forEach(p -> builder.append(p).append(System.lineSeparator()));
    return builder.toString();
}
```

This works but `fileName` can be under a subdir of `/src/test/resources/` anywhere and I prefer not to hard code `app/testcases/` all the time.

Comment: So you want to locate a text file in any sub directory and write to it?

Comment: Possibly a use case for a `FileVisitor`...

Comment: @RR_IL Under `/src/test/resources/` or its subdirs only. I read that file and return a String so I have the `builder.toString()` call at the end.

Comment: @deHaar Do you have a snippet for that?

Comment: @silver You can find an example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) and read the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
public String parse(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Path resourcesPath = Paths.get("src", "test", "resources");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Path filePath = Files.walk(resourcesPath)
            .filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile()
                    && p.getFileName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(fileName))
            .findFirst().orElseThrow();
    Files.lines(filePath.toAbsolutePath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .forEach(p -> builder.append(p).append(System.lineSeparator()));
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Path#resolve`:

```
public static String parse(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Path absoluteFilePath = Paths.get("/src/test/resources").resolve(fileName);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Files.lines(absoluteFilePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .forEach(p -> builder.append(p).append(System.lineSeparator()));
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Or better use a `ClassLoader`:

```
public static String parse(String fileName) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    Path absoluteFilePath = Paths.get(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toURI());
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Files.lines(absoluteFilePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .forEach(p -> builder.append(p).append(System.lineSeparator()));
    return builder.toString();
}
```